# Sonic Pi won't play sound from remote Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, sonic-pi

I am using [`Sonic Pi 3.3.1`](https://sonic-pi.net/) on my Windows PC and a `Python` script(`Python3.7.2`) on my raspberry pi(`Raspbian Buster`) that detects distance from an [`HC-SR04`-Ultrasonic Sensor](https://components101.com/ultrasonic-sensor-working-pinout-datasheet) .The program then creates a tune with a pitch that ranges higher if the object is further away, this tune is then sent over `OSC` to Sonic Pi. External `OSC` is enabled on my windows PC. I also checked the `Port` and `IP` addresses, and they are correct.

I have tested my circuit extensively and I can confidently say this isn't the source of the problem, and that I added it for documentation purposes only at the bottom of my post for anyone who is interested, so I will move on.

**My Python code:**

```
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from time import sleep

from pythonosc import osc_message_builder
from pythonosc import udp_client

sensor = DistanceSensor(echo=17, trigger=4)
sender = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient('10.0.0.119', 4560)

while True:
    pitch = round(sensor.distance * 100 + 30)
    print(pitch)
    sender.send_message('/play_this', pitch)
    sleep(0.1)
```

**Output:**

```
60
60
58
59
```

The problem doesn't seem to be my `python` code as it logs the correct values and successfully sends the pitch so once again I will move on.

**My sonic Pi code:**

```
live_loop :listen do
  use_real_time
  note = sync "/osc/play_this"
  play note[0]
end
```

**Output:**

[image: Sonic Pi Output]

Sonic Pi log's the notes correctly but doesn't play it and this so the data is being received but isn't being played so the problem is most likely how I am trying to play the note but I can't find the correct way to do this

---

**I then tried this, to test if `sonic pi` installed correctly and is able to play sound**:

```
live_loop :foo do
  play 60
  sleep 1
end
```

Sonic Pi did play a sound so I can rule out a defective installation where sound is not installed properly.

---

### My Circuit:

The `Vcc` pin on the [`HC-SR04`-Ultrasonic Sensor](https://components101.com/ultrasonic-sensor-working-pinout-datasheet) is connected to the `5V` power supply on the raspberry pi, then the `Trig` pin is connected to the 4th `GPIO` connector on the board the echo pin is then connected to the 17th `GPIO` connector between a voltage divider consisting of a `330 ohm` resistor and a `470 ohm` resistor which protects the raspberry from a full `5V`.

**My circuit looks like:**
[image: circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

---

The problem is in the Sonic Pi `que path`, that receives the note from the `python` scipt over a `UDP` connection.More specifically it is in the `sync` statement of the `que path`. The sync statement is missing the senders `Ip` address and `Port` which is necessary when using multiple computers unlike in a local environment

You can either explicitly mention the `Ip` address like so:

```
live_loop :listen do
  use_real_time
  note = sync "/osc/10.0.0.80:56505/play_this "#Mention the senders Ip address and port
  play note[0]
end
```

**Or you can tell it to accept input regardless of the sender like so:**

```
live_loop :listen do
  use_real_time
  note = sync "/osc*/play_this "#This accepts a message regardless of the sender
  play note[0]
end
```

---

I would like to end my post by thanking [Sam Aaron](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/17668/sam-aaron) who gave me insight on this problem on the Raspberry pi Stack Exchange community which enabled me to answer my this question